# My PHP file upload script hangs if file size > ~7.5MB, despite changing ini settings

Tags: php, file-upload

I seem to be having problems with my upload script. If I upload a file around 6MB it works fine, but larger than that and it hangs. Here is the page with the upload form: https://amorphia-apparel.com/hirsute/info/upload/

Here are two files to test with, one 6.3MB one 8.8MB:

https://amorphia-apparel.com/carl-sagan-6MB.jpg

https://amorphia-apparel.com/carl-sagan-9MB.jpg

The smaller of the two works perfectly. The larger one, however, according to the chrome progress bar uploads in about 5-6 seconds, then the page hangs with "waiting for amorphia-apparel.com" indefinietly.

Here is my script:

```
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');
    ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
    ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);

    $id = milltime();       

    if( !$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] ) return false;

    $extension = pathinfo( $_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $target_file = HOME_PATH . "images/user/temp/{$id}.{$extension}";

    if( !move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target_file) ){      
          return false;
    }
    else {
          return true;
    }
```

Any clue what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set value of this settings in php.ini or httpd.conf or .htaccess.
look here http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: A Yup, that was it. That's a touch embarrassing.